# Matlab engine.h from existing c++ code for mac?

Tags: c++, matlab, import, compilation, include

I want to open MatLab from an existing c++ code, and I tried `#include <engine.h>` and `#include <the given path for matlab>` and it didn't work.

I also saw that I had to link the libraries in the command line? But I wasn't sure how..

I'm running my computer on my solid state, and Matlab is installed on my hard drive. Is that an issue or am I just failing compiling correctly?

Comment: What didn't work? Compiling, running? Which errors do you get? Have you followed Mathworks' instructions for [Compiling Engine Applications with MEX Command](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_external/compiling-engine-applications-with-the-mex-command.html) or [Compiling Engine Applications with IDE](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_external/compiling-engine-applications-in-an-ide.html).

Comment: Can't help much, but am pretty sure that the drive on which things are installed is not the problem here.

Comment: when I just do a normal 'make' command in terminal, I get "fatal error: 'engine.h' file not found"